# Preventing columns from moving on delete in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to implement a checkbox interface which allows a user to show/hide columns in a JTable, but when I remove the column, the column seems to move position and there is no way of knowing 100% where the columns are. The table is built with this code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table            = new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane  = new JScrollPane(table);

String[] columnNames = {"Artist","Track","Album","Genre","Year","Filetype"};

for (String column : columnNames) {
    model.addColumn(column);
}
table.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
```

Here's the code I have for implementing the checkbox listeners:

```
if (e.getSource() == artist) {
    if (!artist.isSelected()) {
        table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
    } else {
        table.addColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
    }
}
if (e.getSource() == trackName) {
    if (!trackName.isSelected()) {
        table.removeColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
    } else {
        table.addColumn(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1));
    }
}
/* etc */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to use the [Table Column Manager](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/table-column-manager/).

It will manager the hiding/showing of the table columns for you.

Comment: @admrply with convert columns index from view to model (I have for implementing the checkbox listeners)